# java jsp file update table field in database

Tags: java, sqlite, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am trying to update the number of trips done by employees. 
In the table below, I get the list of the employees and the number of trips done by each, and an input field to update that number. However, I get `error 500 null`.
Could somebody help me to resolve this issue? thanks a lot.

inside **Controller.java**

```
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ....

            } else if (methode.equals("post") && action.equals("/updateemployees")) {
                doUpdateEmployee(request, response);
    ....


        private void doUpdateEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


                int tripsInitialvalue = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("nbTrips"));
[line: 177]     int id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));


                EmployeeDAO.addTrips(id,tripsInitialvalue);


                doEmployees(request, response);

            }
```

inside my **EmployeeDAO.java**

```
public static Employee addTrips(int id, int tripsToAdd) {
        EntityManager em = GestionFactory.factory.createEntityManager();
        Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, id);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        int tripsInitialvalue = employee.getNbTrips();
        employee.setNbTrips(tripsInitialvalue + tripsToAdd);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return employee;
    }
```

and my **employees.jsp** file:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/do/updateemployees">  
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number of Trips</th>        
        <th>Edit Trips</th>
    <tr>
<% for (Employee employee : employees) {%>
    <tr>
        <td><%=employee.getId()%></td>
        <td><%=employee.getName()%></td>        
        <td><%=employee.getNbTrips()%></td>     
        <td><input type="number" name="nbTrips" size="2" value="<%=employee.getNbTrips()%>"></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

### error log:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - null
message null
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    projet.controleur.Controleur.doUpdateEmployee(Controller.java:177)
    projet.controleur.Controleur.doGet(Controller.java:109)
    projet.controleur.Controleur.doPost(Controller.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: post the error stack trace and relevant code lines.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda please see the updated question , added the error log and the line number in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so from the error details it is apparent that the valueOf is trying to parse **null** in the code.you cannot parse a "null" to int.

```
if(request.getParameter("id") != null) {

int id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
EmployeeDAO.addTrips(id,tripsInitialvalue);

} else {
  //decide what to do when id is null
}
```

**EDIT :**
To get values of all textboxes use request.getParameterValues('nbTrips'), this will return all the values for elements with same 'nbTrips'

```
String[] nbTrips = request.getPrameterValues('nbTrips')
```

will return all the text box values with name 'nbTrips' into String array nbTrips which you can iterate and get each values from textBox.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, the previous error has gone.  but when i change the number and click on update, the value doesn't get updated.

Comment: because it jumps to the else part and nothing happens. what should I do to update the field?

Comment: if it jumps to else mean it is still null,keep a debug and see what value you are getting at req.getParameter

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to pass the `id` of the employee alongside the new trip number in the form to send it to the controller, as it needs two parameters the id and the new trip value. can you help to correctly write my form? thanks

Comment: but when i add this id code, it only updates the first one in the list. I have the list of all employees, and the input field is editable for all, so i'd like to put new values for all and update them all at once.

Comment: and this makes the id field seem editable as well, which is misleading. so i need to pass the id secretly to the parameters without being noticed by the user.

Comment: @someangular : check the edit to get the idea on how to get multiple values. since your original problem "error 500" is answered please accept the answer and raise a different question with your new requirement.